# How do I call the view method in the onCreate Java lifecycle?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have a problem when I want to use setText but when it is called directly on onCreate it can't?

This is my method:

```
    public void onSendData(View view) {
        long seek = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
        WritableMap args = Arguments.createMap();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        args.putInt("seek", (int) seek);
        args.putString("type", "paused");
        args.putString("name", playingVideo.getString("name"));
        args.putString("category_name", playingVideo.getString("category_name"));
        args.putString("date", playingVideo.getString("date"));
        sendEvent(reactContext, "onSendData", args);
        textName.setText(playingVideo.getString("name") + " " + playingVideo.getString("category_name"));
        textDate.setText(playingVideo.getString("date"));
        textCustomerName.setText(playingVideo.getString("customer_name"));
        textEstimate.setText(playingVideo.getString("estimate"));
        textPaid.setText(playingVideo.getString("paid"));
        textPrice.setText(playingVideo.getString("price"));
        textAddress.setText(playingVideo.getString("address"));
        textLongAddress.setText(playingVideo.getString("long_address"));


    }
```

And this is the code when I call on the onCreate lifecycle:

```
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        onSendData();
      ........
      .....
     }
```

Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, are you calling this on a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: Cannot be applied to ()

Comment: I call in Activity.

Comment: Are you setting the text in a TextView or Edittext? Also, can you post more code on how you are grabbing the views from xml and your xml layout?

Comment: @zidniryi You have to pass the view instance on the `onSendData()` function

Comment: can you show me the best implementation code ?. Thanks, Christilyn & Saugat

Comment: make sure that you're calling onSendData() after setContentView(); method

Comment: Still not working yet. for change, the text in XML must be trigger by the click button.

Comment: it will be helpfull if you past logcat -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is the problem but I would do it like this:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        loadViews();       //create instance of view objects textName, textDate, etc. 
        onSendData(null);  //passing View as null 
      ........
      .....
     }
```

Comment: where loadViews(); comes from ??

Comment: It is where you create instance of xml view objects.